# Memory Allocation in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, memory, glut, allocation

This is more of a discussion question that one that has a straight answer. I'm developing a fairly simple scene in OpenGL, and have come across an issue with the class structure I'm using. I have a 'Primitive' base class, off of which I'm building derived classes such as Cube, Tetrahedron, Sphere etc. The base class holds all of the data about the object, such as it's vertices and normals. From here, I have several classes derived from a Model class such as Fence, which then contains several cubes arranged to make the correct structure. I'm storing all of the vertices and normals in the heap, and need a way to free the memory. However, when trying to free the memory in the Primitive's constructor, I come across an error.

I think this is because, when using GLUT, the models are defined outside of glutMainLoop(), and so they go out of scope before the program is done using them. Is there a more efficient way to manage memory with vertex arrays in OpenGL? Or is there a workaround for this problem?

Comment: glutMainLoop never returns. what exactly do you ask?

Comment: If you are going to vote someones question down please give them the courtesy of say why

Comment: @doron I just voted close as not a real question, not vote down. Anyway, people are free to down vote without explaining why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using client side buffers for your model, use serverside buffer. These are bound using `glGenBuffer glBindBuffer and glBufferData`. These APIs upload your buffers into server memory and once uploaded you can immediately free your data.

Newer versions of OpenGL have Vertex Array Objects (VAOs) that may help you as well.